# SQL Server Integration Services. Dynamic changing of connection string by package parameters inside of foreach

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to get data from several databases using SQL Server Integration Services (more than 20) and for each of them execute the package that transfers the data to a target database, there is a table with a list of connection strings of these databases in other database.

I try to execute the `ExecutePackage` task inside `foreach` task and send connection string from query as package's parameter, also I send connection string of target database and date. But package stops with error:

> [Importing [11]] Error: SSIS error code: DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The call to the AcquireConnection method of the connection manager "targetdb" failed with error code 0xC0202009. You may have previously published error messages that contain more detailed information about the reason for the failure of the AcquireConnection method.

I think the connection manager of targetdb does not pass validation, in this case I run package directly from Visual Studio. When I run package separately (not inside foreach and with default parameters), then it works right.

Is it right way for my task?

Comment: how could you iterate each connection string inside the foreach loop?

Comment: I placed result of connection strings query to variable `Connections` and created `Connection` variable for `foreach` loop, for each step it changes Connection variable, Connection variable mapped to connection string parameter of package, which loads data with dynamic connection. Connection manager of this package has Connection String property, I assigned it parameter value (I used expression property of connection manager).

Comment: didi you notice the scope of the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decision was simple. I set `DelayValidation` property to true for package, which executed inside foreach loop, it decided problem.